# how do i solve git clone issue return connection error 403

Tags: linux, github, centos

im on centos 8 want to git clone but suddenly not working and just return failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out.

try setting up the company proxy but still not working. So yeah, need help here.

Comment: Where does port 443 come from?

Comment: how to check it? sorry from beginner

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to [edit] your question and add more details, so that people can reproduce or at least understand the issue. Where do you clone from? What command do you use exactly? Is there a firewall? Does it always fail like that? See [ask].